# ExtJS4 XTemplates in view;

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

my question is: 
"What is the right way to operate with XTemplates in a **MVC** like project in ExtJS4?"

---

> Are XTemplates supposed to be in YourApp.**view** or in YourApp.**controller**?
The ExtJS4 docs just shows how to use XTemplates with some data, but i haven't seen a MVC-like example.
So,

- Where should our XTemplates take place at?
- Can XTemplate take some variable from controller as argument? *(in case i would get some calculated data in controller and every time those data changes they should be passed to XTemplate and this XTemplate should form and render new template to the webpage;*

P.S.
Sorry for my English and Thanks for your help;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but i can share with you/SOF a few thoughts and hopefully help you out to understand more the templating engine of extjs.

In very general terms, the XTemplate is what a view/control(grid, texfield, etc) is built on. Every component control in extjs has a "Tpl" or "fieldSubTpl" or "subTpl" etc.. config options which is the XTemplate to use to render the component UI.

So, imagine you are using extjs native class "Ext.form.field.TextArea" which represents an input text control, if you look in the source code of extjs framework (I think people often forget about checking out the source code, learn and get inspired from it, get the grip on things, see how extjs dev. team does things) and locate the class definition for it, and you will be able to see how the XTemplate is used. So I think if you can check this out and understand it, ofc, sencha docs is a valuable resource, you get already some answers.

XTemplate takes an array with data/single object whose properties need to match the variable inside the XTemplate, so you got an object representing a person and a property name i.e. `person.Name` so in  your xtemplate would would show the name by using {Name} inside the xtemplate. You mention about doing some calculation in the controller and then pass it into the XTemplate, that is fine you can do it, but remember that the XTemplate support custom functions which can manipulate the data before the Xtemplate is rendered as you can see in this example from sencha docs http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

If you want an MVC application which uses XTemplates explicitly, you can check the "MVC Feed viewer" app from sencha here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/feed-viewer/feed-viewer.html

I hope it helps you.

Happy Easter!

Comment: Though it isn't the most "relevant" answer to my question but it really helped. Thanks and Happy Easter to you ;)